# Join parameter labels then separate by commas, join not working as expected

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

**Current Code**

`="Project Groups: " + replace(join(Parameters!projGroup.Label )," ",", ")`

**Problem**

Works fine if projGroup are one word.  Ex:  Group1, Group2, Group3.

My client has a change in requirement... Groups are no longer one word.

Ex:

Group A

This Group

That Group

**I need Need this to Display:** Group A, This Group, That Group

**But it's currently displaying this:**  Group, A, This, Group, That, Group

Comment: I don't really understand. Is `Display` what you get now?, or what you want?. Can you clarify that, what is it that it does now, and what is it that you want it to do

Comment: @Lamak Thanks.  Edited for clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to use `REPLACE`, can't you just do the following?:

```
="Project Groups: " + join(Parameters!projGroup.Label,", ")
```